# C#: How to open multiple word documents from a folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, automation, office-interop

I have a folder with three word documents named Test1, Test2, and Test3 all with the docx extension.

I know if we want to manually open a file we can specify a filepath and use the following code:

```
Word.Application fileOpen = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = fileOpen.Documents.Open(filePath);
```

However is there any other way to select that folder but open up one file at a time? I would like to do the following:

1. Open up Test1.docx -> make some changes -> save -> close
2. Open up Test2.docx -> repeat above, and lastly do the same for Test3.docx

I've searched everywhere but can't find something relating to this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I have included a sample code and explanation below.

You must use the following for this!

```
Using System.IO;
```

For this example we will look at getting all the "doc" and "docx" files from the Desktop directory.

```
//Directory to search through:
string sampleFilePath = @"C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop";

//Now we create a list to hold all the filepaths that exist in this directory
List<string> allFilePaths = new List<string>();
//Extract all doc/docx files on Desktop
string[] start = Directory.GetFiles(sampleFilePath, "*doc");
        for (int begin = 0; begin < start.Length; begin++)
        {
            allFilePaths.Add(start[begin]);
        }

//The above code does not extract doc/docx files that are contained inside folders that exist on desktop.
//So we need to get those filepaths separately.
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(sampleFilePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            //Any doc and docx files found in the subdirectories are added to the list
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filePaths[i], "*doc");
            for (int j = 0; j < files.Length; j++)
            {
                allFilePaths.Add(files[j]);
            }
            //Continue checking the subdirectories for more folders until you reach the end, then move on to the second subdirectory from the very beginning.
            string[] checkMoreDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePaths[i]);
            checkForMoreDirectories(checkMoreDirectories, ref allFilePaths);
        }
```

The checkForMoreDirectories method is given below.

```
static void checkForMoreDirectories (string[] checkMoreDirectories, ref List<string> myList)
    {
        //This function calls itself recursively for every subdirectory within the previous subdirectory until it reaches the end where there are no more folders left
        //Continuously add any doc/docx files found before going deeper into the subdirectory
        for (int i = 0; i < checkMoreDirectories.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(checkMoreDirectories[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < files.Length; j++)
            {
                myList.Add(files[j]);
            }
            string[] temp = Directory.GetDirectories(checkMoreDirectories[i]);
            //Recursive call
            checkForMoreDirectories(temp, ref myList);
        }
    }
```

Now even if you have 1000 folders each with many subfolders that store doc/docx files, you will have the filepaths for each one of those stored in your list. Then you can access this list and open each file through the use of the Microsoft Word Interops and make changes etc.

Comment: Hé @Dylan, the OP of the other answer expected a different outcome when they provided their answer also based on your comments. If you feel for it do you mind chiming in on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351673/578411)?. We don't bite ...

Comment: There are a few things to mention here.

1. I did up vote his answer however it says, "Votes cast by less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not publicly change display".
2. Yes his answer was correct and I did as I mentioned in 1.
3. The code I have posted is significantly different than his, it worked for a larger scale of sub folders existing within one another.

Comment: Yes, the reputation requirement was indeed noticed by commenters on the meta post and I made that explicit in my meta answer. That you needed an solution for a folder wasn't clear from the question which I think feeds the surprise of the other answerer. AFAICT we're all good now. Thanks for your comment, enjoy your day.

Comment: @Dylan you plagiarized my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For this scenario, let's assume that you already know which folder you want to open & read files from.

First, you've got to import System.IO

```
using System.IO;
```

Within that namespace, Directory.GetFiles() will give you the filenames within a string array.

```
private static void FolderReader()
{
    string folderPath = @"C:\someFolder\";
    Word.Application fileOpen = new Word.Application();
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        Word.Document document = fileOpen.Documents.Open(filePath);
        // perform continue with your algorithm...
        // close the file when you're done.
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. Good luck.